# Why do I not get a compiler error in change of type of foreach over IEnumeable<T>?

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

I write a generic class that implement `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class EnumerableObject<T> :  IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So i can iterate over object of this class with `foreach` but if i change type of foreach variable, Compiler not give me a error and i can write this code without compiler error:

```
foreach (string item in new EnumerableObject<int>())
{
    ....
}
```

But if i iterate over a generic list i got a compiler error:

```
foreach (string item in new List<int>())
{
    ...
}
```

> Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'

I think `List<T>` class condition is like my class EnumerableObject but why i not get a compiler error in my case?

Comment: You're trying to iterate an int with a string. That will never work. Why are you using string?

Comment: @CathalMF, If i read question completely i try to simulate a conflicting situation to clarify question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens is that because your non-generic `GetEnumerator` method is `public`, it is the one implicitly being used be the `foreach` statement. Thus, it effectively returns a non-generic `IEnumerator`, allowing you to write `foreach (string item in new EnumerableObject<int>())`, which will explode at run-time.

If you make the non-generic `GetEnumerator` method private, you'll see the compile time warning. You should actually be doing it the other way around:

```
public class EnumerableObject<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Implement.
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right... Now you should show him the "more correct code" with the swapperd `GetEnumerator()`: `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`